# Different title and description tags for Django site with pagination

Tags: django, pagination, title

I have a web site running on django and use pagination for some of my pages. Search engines demand different title and description tags for every page.

Is it possible somehow differentiate title and description tags for different pages with similar name (https://bratus.net/listings/?page=2), for example using part of pagination code in title ?

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option: as part of your view for the `/listings/` endpoint, include the page number in the data you send to the template:

`return render(request, 'my_template.html', { ..., 'page_number': page_number or 1 })`

Then in your template, you can do something like:

`<title>Listings, Page {{ page_number }}</title>`

And a similar thing for your meta tags.